# How to linq OrderBy on a nested table field?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

I have a list of reports and each report has a number of "Nets". Each of these "Nets" has a status and I would like to reorder these reports based on the statuses they may have. I am writing my LINQ expression incorrectly because what is in my OrderBy() parenthesis isn't an actual single field to be orderable. Here's how it looks:

```
reports.OrderBy(r => r.Nets.Where(n => n.NetStatus.Equals("New")).OrderBy(n => n.NetId))
    .ThenBy(r => r.Nets.Where(n => n.NetStatus.Equals("Updated")).OrderBy(n => n.NetId))
    .ThenBy(r => r.Nets.Where(n => n.NetStatus.Equals("Ignored")).OrderBy(n => n.NetId))
```

Because it is not an actual orderable field in the OrderBy and ThenBy clauses, an error is being thrown saying "DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable parameter Name: Key", which honestly makes sense. What I am unable to figure out is how to properly convey what I am trying to order as stated in the first paragraph correctly.

Comment: So you want all the Nets of all the reports with a status of New first, then Updated, then Ignored and then order each of those groups by the id?  It seems like you'll need to flatten the structure to do that.  Or just start with the "Nets" table instead.

Comment: Is the dataset too large to just bring into memory and then do the order? cause i think the issue is when it tries to translate the IQueryable to sql

Comment: *as stated in the first paragraph correctly* Frankly, it's unclear what do you mean by *ordering reports based on statuses they may have*. What's the order rule for report with multiple statuses?

Comment: To be clear, and I think to the point that @IvanStoev is making, you are trying to order the **`reports`**, not the **`nets`** of each report, correct? And if that's the case, then it's not clear what the rule of ordering should be. If two reports each have two nets, but one has two "New" nets and the other has a "New" and an "Updated" net, then which comes first? What if there is a third report that has 2 "New" and 1 "Ignored" net. Where should that fall within the order? You need to define the order before anyone can give a proper answer.

Comment: agreed, struggling with the same thing on my end

Comment: Some sample input and output would have made this question 100% more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could try breaking out the top layer Linq statement into a `foreach` and creating a list for each type of `NetStatus` that you have. You can then combine your lists for an ordered result.

```
foreach (var r in reports)
    {
        var newList = r.Nets.Where(n => n.NetStatus.Equals("New")).OrderBy(n => n.NetId).ToList();

        var upatedList = r.Nets.Where(n => n.NetStatus.Equals("Updated")).OrderBy(n => n.NetId).ToList();

        var IgnoredList = r.Nets.Where(n => n.NetStatus.Equals("Ignored")).OrderBy(n => n.NetId).ToList();

        var result = newList.Concat(upatedList).Concat(IgnoredList);
    }
```

Building off of the code above; to sort the `Reports` in the order of `Reports` that contain at least 1 'New' NetStatus, then `Reports` that contain at least 1 `Updated` NetStatus, then the remaining `Reports`, we can add each `r` object to an independent list based off of the count of each type of `Status List` we created above:

```
        var sortedReports = new List<Report>();

        foreach (var r in reports)
        {
            var newList = r.Nets.Where(n => n.NetStatus.Equals("New")).OrderBy(n => n.NetId).ToList();
            var upatedList = r.Nets.Where(n => n.NetStatus.Equals("Updated")).OrderBy(n => n.NetId).ToList();
            var IgnoredList = r.Nets.Where(n => n.NetStatus.Equals("Ignored")).OrderBy(n => n.NetId).ToList();

            if (newList.Count > 0)
            {
                sortedReports.Add(r);
            }
            else if (upatedList.Count > 0)
            {
                sortedReports.Add(r);
            }
            else
            {
                sortedReports.Add(r);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I appologize if it wasn't clear, but I'm trying to sort the list of reports themselves based off this nested information.

Comment: I think I'm having trouble understanding exactly how you're expecting your `Reports` to be sorted. Do you want your `Reports` sorted by which one has the most `New` statuses, followed by the most `Updated`, then the most `Ignored`?

Comment: More like, reports that have at least one status of "New", sort first. Then "Updated", then "Ignored". Now in regards to how all the reports with "New" should be sorted, it really doesn't matter much; maybe sort those by their reportId.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a list `netStatusList` filled and ordered by nets statuses (this is to help you in making a custom sorting).
2. Flatten your reports to one list of Nets.
3. Order by each net status index in  `netStatusList` and then by the net ID.

   ```
   List<String> netStatusList= new List<String> { "New",  "Updated", "Ignored"  };

   reports.SelectMany(r => r.Nets).ToList().OrderBy(n => netStatusList.IndexOf(n.NetStatus))
   .ThenBy(n => n.NetId);
   ```

Comment: When you do the to SelectMany, you lose the Id

Comment: @Vnvizitiu I don't think so, since NetId is a property for each Net not Report.

Comment: you're right, my bad, made the model wrong, rechecked it

Comment: @Vnvizitiu no problem :)

Comment: This is helpful because at least the Nets are now ordered properly but this doesn't actually return the reports sorted properly, which is what I was having trouble with.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make your Nets ordering on reports level ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Nets ordering on reports level", but I am trying to get the reports themselves sorted based on this information.

Answer (score 1):

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492950/how-to-linq-orderby-on-a-nested-table-field/46493257#comment79943830_46493257) on one of the current answers (which should really be part of the question):

> More like, reports that have at least one status of "New", sort first. Then "Updated", then "Ignored". Now in regards to how all the reports with "New" should be sorted, it really doesn't matter much; maybe sort those by their reportId.

you are seeking for some sort of a *priority order*.

To achieve that, you could assign a priority to each status using a conditional expression like

```
status == "New" ? 1 :
status == "Updated" ? 2 :
status == "Ignored" ? 3 : 4
```

which should translate to SQL `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE .. END` expression.

Also, since you have potentially multiple statuses, you can use `Min` function to determine the priority of the main record, and then use that for ordering.

Putting it into action (`DefaultIfEmpty()` is to handle empty `r.Nets`):

```
var query = reports
    .OrderBy(r => r.Nets.DefaultIfEmpty().Min(n => 
         n.NetStatus == "New" ? 1 :
         n.NetStatus == "Updated" ? 2 :
         n.NetStatus == "Ignored" ? 3 :
         4))
    .ThenBy(r => r.ReportId);
```

or in case the query provider does not handle transparently `null` records (as EF provider does):

```
var query = reports
    .OrderBy(r => r.Nets.Select(n => n.NetStatus).DefaultIfEmpty().Min(status => 
         status == "New" ? 1 :
         status == "Updated" ? 2 :
         status == "Ignored" ? 3 :
         4))
    .ThenBy(r => r.ReportId);
```

Whichever works and translates better.

Answer (score 0):

if you are aiming to to get the Nets of each report

```
reports.SelectMany(r => r.Nets).GroupBy(e=> e.NetStatus).Select(e=> new 
{
   Key = e.Key,
   List = e.OrderBy(e=> e.NetId)
});
```

however if you the reports then you can

```
reports.Select(report => new 
{
    Report = report,
    Nets = report.Nets.GroupBy(e=> e.NetStatus).Select(e=> new {
               Key = e.Key,
               List = e.OrderBy(e=> e.NetId)
           });
});
```

Comment: duly noted will pay attention next time

Comment: I am editing it now, and what I meant was it won't happen in the future

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be misunderstanding how OrderBy is intended to work. You don't provide the items you want ordered first, you provide a `value` to order on. So in your case, you want to order on `NetStatus`, however, if you just did `reports.OrderBy(r => r.NetStatus)`, it will sort alphabetically on NetStatus.

Instead, you need to return a value that sorts correctly based on the order you actually want it sorted. Consider something like this:

```
reports.OrderBy(r => {
switch(r.NetStatus){
case "New": return 1;
case "Updated": return 2;
case "Ignored": return 3;
}
})
```

Now, you're returning values 1, 2, or 3 *BASED* on the value of `NetStatus`, however, the 1, 2, and 3 will sort correctly.
You can then follow that up with `.ThenBy(n => n.NetId)` to sort by the `NetId` field AFTER sorting by the NetStatus field.

Edit: IvanStoev pointed out below that NetStatus is actually a property on the Net collection, not report directly. You will likely need to adjust my example to compensate, but hopefully it gets the idea across. You need to provide a single solitary value for OrderBy to sort on, not a collection of values.

Full example:

```
 class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      List<Report> reports = new List<Report>();
      reports.Add(new Report() { NetStatus = "Updated", NetId = 1 });
      reports.Add(new Report() { NetStatus = "New", NetId = 2 });
      reports.Add(new Report() { NetStatus = "Ignored", NetId = 4 });
      reports.Add(new Report() { NetStatus = "Ignored", NetId = 3 });

      var orderedReports = reports.OrderBy((r) => {
        switch (r.NetStatus) {
          case "New": return 1;
          case "Updated": return 2;
          case "Ignored": return 3;
          default: return 0;
        }
      }).ThenBy(r => r.NetId);

      foreach (var report in orderedReports) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{report.NetId} {report.NetStatus}");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
  public class Report {
    public String NetStatus { get; set; }
    public int NetId { get; set; }
  }
```

Output

```
2 New
1 Updated
3 Ignored
4 Ignored
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this should be done on IEnumerable not IQueryable, i don't think the custom func would translate to SQL, otherwise Tyler is onto something

Comment: The problem is that `r.Nets` from OP seems to be a collection. I don't see how your answer is addressing that (which is unclear anyway).

Comment: @IvanStoev ah, you are correct. I missed that bit. Added a note along those lines. The idea is still sound, OP will have to adjust as necessary.

Comment: @Vnvizitiu You are right, but the `switch` block can easily be converted to conditional operator expression (`x == "New" ? 1 : x == "Updated" ? 2 : ...`) which is supported in expression trees and is convertible to SQL.

Comment: NetStatus is not on the report but on each of the items in a collection of Nets tied to a report. That's the tricky part...

Comment: @LaRaeWhite That's fine, but you still need to propagate that up to a single sorting value at the report level if you want the reports to be sorted. Could be something like `r.Nets.Any(n => n.NetStatus == "New") return 1` in the switch statement above.

Comment: @Tyler Lee, I don't see how you could work that Any() clause into your switch statement really. What would you switch on?

Comment: @LaRaeWhite ahh, you're right. i didn't actually write it so I thought wrong. It could have to be something like what IvanStoev did above with the ternary, or a series of if statements. 

Of course, this may not fully meet your need, but i'm hoping it at least gives you some ideas on how to proceed.